# My html webpage messes up when I resize it

Tags: html, css, resize

I just started making this website, I don't know why but when I resize it, the page goes all crazy. Some problem is that my header goes weird and same with the task bar. Please help me. Here is my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <style type="text/css">
     body{
        font-family: arial;
        text-align: center;
     }

    *{ 
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
    }
    #div1{
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        height: 550px;
        background-image: url("C:\\Users\\muadh\\Pictures\\harvest5.jpg");


    }
    #div2{
        background: #A3E4E7;
        height: 70px;
        width: 100%;
         line-height: 70px;

    }
    #div2 li{
        list-style-type: none;
        position: static;
        float: left;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 10px;

    }
    #div2 ul{
        position: static;
            float: right;

    }
    #div2 ul li{
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #div2 ul li a{
        padding: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
    #div2 ul li:hover{
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
        background: #0767B6;  /*#E06300*/

    }

    h1{
        position: absolute; 
        height:60px;       
        top: 120px;     
        z-index: 99;             
        font-family: "arial"; 
        font-size: 60px; 
        padding: 2px;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 67px;  
        padding: 100%
        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;  
    }
    h3{
        position: absolute;yt

        font-size: 30px;
        height: 60px;
        top: 230px;
        padding-left: 67px;  
        list-style-type: none;
        float: left;
        color: white;
    }
     #link1 {border-radius: 100%;}

  </style>
 <head>
    <title>Metis Microsystem</title>
    <link rel = "icon" type = "image/jpg" href = "C:\Users\muadh\Pictures\circuit.jpg" id = "link1"/>
 </head>

  <body>
        <div id = "div1">
                <div id = "div2">
                   <div id = "nav_wrapper">                 
            <head>

                </head>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Founders</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
          </div>
          <h1>xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx</h1>
          <h3>x xxxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx</h3>        
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The first obvious problem is that you are opening 3 `<div>` but only ever close 2. Next, referencing images with absolute paths to your local drive will break when uploading your site. Apart from that you should be a little more specific about *"goes weird"* since we cannot reproduce without the background-image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not copy paste, learn by yourself.

- There are tags which were opened but never closed.
- `<head>` tags defined twice, one in body (?)
- `<style>` tags defined before, outside `<head>` (first one)
- None of your elements has 'position' property', or if they do, it is absolute.
- list-type in `<h3>`
- You are missing ';' every two lines.

I advice you to start with https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp first.

Comment: you're far better off not engaging in back-and-forths in the comments.